# Javascript: Add a parameter after an URL

Tags: javascript, json, url, parameters

I'd like to add a parameter after an URL in a Javascript function. 
The full URL I'd like to have is: https://my-url.com/section1/section2/here_a_random_number**.json?lang=en**
This is the ".json?lang=en" that I'd like to add at the end of the URL.

Here my function (in a Google script, linked to a sheet):

```
  function myfunction(randomnumber) {
  var myUrl = "https://my-url.com/section1/section2/" + escape(randomnumber);
  var jsonData = UrlFetchApp.fetch(myUrl);
  var jsonString = jsonData.getContentText();
  var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString).result;
  var name = (jsonObject.name);
  Utilities.sleep(2000);
return name;
}
```

Where could I put/add my language parameter ?

Comment: So what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just add it to the end of the URL:

```
var myUrl = "https://my-url.com/section1/section2/" + escape(randomnumber) + ".json?lang=en";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works ! :) (Sorry if my question was stupid but it's the first I use programmation language)

Answer (score 1):

try to replace

```
var myUrl = "https://my-url.com/section1/section2/" + escape(randomnumber);
```

by
`var myUrl = "https://my-url.com/section1/section2/" + escape(randomnumber)+".json?lang=en";`

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works ! :) (Sorry if my question was stupid but it's the first I use programmation language)